# Form handling for generic class in Play Framework 2.3.x

Tags: forms, validation, scala, inheritance, playframework-2.3

I have a set of model classes on the basis of a `sealed trait` like the following:

```
sealed trait Base {
   def baseValue: String
}

case class ChildA(
   baseValue: String
   childAValue: Int
) extends Base

case class ChildB(
   baseValue: String
   childBValue: String
) extends Base
```

How do I handle the [form submission](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms) properly, i.e. how can I define a [Form](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Forms$) that yields objects of type `Base` based on the given input data. I am expecting an extra field `$type` that holds the class type information for the specific subtype. Ideally, the form would also handle unknown types with a respective form error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your form to yield an object of type `Base` (i.e. either of type `ChildA` or of type `ChildB`), maybe you should take a look into Scala's `Either` type. More here: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/02/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-7-the-either-type.html

Comment: I have simplified the model structure for this question. Actually, the `Base` class has more than two subclasses. The idea is, that the form should yield `Base` instances and not `Either[ChildA, ChildB]`

Comment: Then I guess you're going to need constructors to instantiate instances of type `Base` in your subclasses, via apply methods maybe. Also implicit converters for each subtype that would cast them to type `Base` might just work too.